# Graceful Shutdown workers

Tags: go, concurrency

The following code should work as per following the examples in [gracefully-shutting-down-multiple-workers-in-go#coordinating-with-context](https://stephenafamo.com/blog/posts/gracefully-shutting-down-multiple-workers-in-go#coordinating-with-context)

Where is the bug in here, why does it not stop at all when I hit Ctrl+C (sigint)?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    go func() {
        signals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
        signal.Notify(signals, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
        <-signals

        cancel()
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        if err := myWorker(ctx); err != nil {
            cancel()
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        if err := startServer(ctx); err != nil {
            cancel()
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}

func myWorker(ctx context.Context) error {
    shouldStop := false

    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()
        shouldStop = true
    }()

    for !shouldStop {
        for {
            fmt.Println("https://gosamples.dev is the best")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func startServer(ctx context.Context) error {

    var srv http.Server

    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done() // Wait for the context to be done

        // Shutdown the server
        if err := srv.Shutdown(context.Background()); err != nil {
            // Error from closing listeners, or context timeout:
            log.Printf("HTTP server Shutdown: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        // Error starting or closing listener:
        return fmt.Errorf("HTTP server ListenAndServe: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: the nested for loop, can't exit.

Comment: And by default the `srv` will listen on port `80`, which will fail with `listen tcp :80: bind: permission denied` most of the time. And there is a data race on the variable `shouldStop`.

Comment: your code doesn't exactly the same as original, try to find it, If the original works and your not work try to find the different.

Answer (score 0):

The nested loop in the worker never stops, I think that Trock is trying to say.

Also in `if err := srv.Shutdown(context.Background()); err != nil {` shouldn't you be passing `ctx` instead?

You might consider [errgroup](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup) to capture the errors form the routines.